# Factorial of zero is 1. Why?

Tags: exponentiation, factorial

Why is the factorial of zero, one. What is the mathematical proof behind it?

Answer (score 4):

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mfk_L4Nx2ZI). Two reasons are:

1. We want the functional equation $n!=(n-1)!n$ to hold when $n=1$.
2. $0!$ should be the number of different ways of arranging $0$ items in a row. There is precisely one way of doing it (the empty arrangement).

Comment: Also, ${m\choose n} = m!/n!/(m-n)!$ is the number of ways of choosing $n$ objects from a set of $m$.  This should work and should return $1$ for $n=m$ or $n=0$.

Comment: You could also say there are no ways of arranging $0$ items, because you can't arrange them. A bit like how you could argue that $x/0$ should be $x$, because you're not doing any dividing. For reasons like this, I think edge cases like this are best handled formally, rather than trying to give intuitive explanations, which tend to collapse when examined more closely.

Answer (score 3):

The proof is somewhat boring: we review the *definition* of the factorial

> - $0! = 1$
> - $(n+1)! = (n+1) n!$ for $n \geq 0$

and therefore, our proof is one line:

> $0! = 1$

What you *really* want to ask is probably

> Why is the factorial defined in such a way that $0! = 1$?

and there are a number of explanations. The simplest, if you can wrap your head around degenerate cases, is that $n!$ is equal to the number of ways to order a list of $n$ objects, and there is simply one way to order a list of zero objects. e.g. see below for that ordering:

> 

Answer (score 1):

We generally want the factorial to satisfy: $n(n-1)!=n!$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ but if we put $n=1$ then we arrive at $0!=1!=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The Gamma function 
$$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$
has the property
$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$
so we find easily that
$$\Gamma(n+1)=n!$$
so
$$0!=\Gamma(1)=1$$

Comment: Tuff to understand.

Answer (score 0):

$(n+1)! = (n+1) * n!$. Take $n=0$.

Comment: But factorial is defined in another way as n multiplied by decrementing n up-to zero. So 0 will result in zero.

Comment: decrementing n down to 1-- which doesn't make sense for n = 0, so we seek another uniform property of factorial in order to extend the definition. Similarly, why is 4 to the -1 power equal to 1/4? "multiply it by itself -1 times" doesn't make sense, so instead we use other properties to extend the definition to negative exponents.